# Functions that eventually invert themselves

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, inverse-function

Functions $f(x)$ with the property $f^2(x)=x$ are called *involutory*. I've been calling functions with the property $f^n(x)=x$ *n-involutory*. I've found a couple different functions of the form
$$f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
that are *2-involutory*, *3-involutory*, and *4-involutory*, and even *6-involutory*, but none that are *5-involutory*. Can anybody find one?

Also, can anyone find an *n-involutory* function with $n \gt 2$ that is not in that form (is not a rational function)?

Thanks! Everything I know so far can be found [here](http://franklin.dyer.me/entries/2017-4-17.html).

Comment: Permutations of an n-set give an abundance of examples.

Comment: I guess that you are looking for fairly well behaved functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Multiplication with a primitive fifth root of unity?

Comment: $f(x)=\big(\cos(2\pi/N)+i\sin(2\pi/N)\big)x$ will have $f^N(x)=f(x)$

Comment: Oh, wait, misunderstood the question

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for functions mapping reals onto reals.

Comment: @FoobazJohn How so? I don't see how the permutations function has this property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a real rational function $f$ such that $f^5=\mathrm{id}$. Let $\zeta=2\pi/5$ and let
$$f(x)=\frac{x\cos\zeta-\sin\zeta}{x\sin\zeta+\cos\zeta}.$$
In other words, it is the fractional linear transformation given by the standard $2\times2$ rotation matrix performing one-fifth of a full revolution. [Your link](http://franklin.dyer.me/entries/2017-4-17.html) explains how this correspondence between rational functions and matrices works.

(Note that $f$ has a pole, so it isn't really a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. You can think of it as a function on the real projective line instead. The same is true of most of the functions in your link, so I assume you don't mind!)

As for non-rational functions, as Foobaz John suggests, you can do pretty much anything. For example, consider the function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $g:1\mapsto2\mapsto3\mapsto4\mapsto5\mapsto6\mapsto7\mapsto1$ and $g(x)=x$ for all other numbers. In other words, $g$ permutes seven chosen numbers and does nothing else. Then $g$ is $7$-involutory.

Comment: So if I wanted a rational *n-involutory* function, I would only need to use $$f(x)=\frac{x\cos\zeta-\sin\zeta}{x\sin\zeta+\cos\zeta}$$ where $\zeta=\frac{2\pi}{n}$?

Comment: Also, I understand the permutation thing that he was suggesting now... I was looking for something that doesn't just permute a finite amount of numbers. The thing I'm looking for is that special property in functions that allows the operators to "undo" each other after a certain number of iterations, and using permutations of an *n-set* seems like cheating.